# AjaxFileUpload Issue not showing up properly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've recently started working on a new project and have come across some difficulties using the AjaxControlToolkit (more specifically the AjaxFileUpload control).  I've used this toolkit and control on other projects successfully but I'm not sure what's going on in this one.  I've referenced the AjaxControlToolkit, put the required lines in my web.config, put the required lines in my aspx pages and set up a script manager and everything seems to be good.  The site launches without error and it sort of shows up but it's not working properly.  Basically what's showing up is a blacked out box that looks like the "Upload" button, which when clicked allows me to select a file.  However none of the other functionality of the control is working.  The first two blocks in the image are two seperate FileUploadControls and the 3rd block is an asyncfileupload control....Anyone have any idea what's going on!?!

see image here: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/3417/screenshot20130223at111.png

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %> //at top of page



<AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm1" runat="server"></AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> //on page

<AjaxControlToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxupload1" runat="server" />//on page
        <pages>//web.config
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
```

As I've said the project builds and launches fine, no errors, and as you can see in the screenshot it attempts to build the controls but something is off...

Comment: It is difficult to help you with problems in your code without seeing your code.

Comment: Added code samples for reference, although they are really just basic; nothing complex...

Comment: @JordanMurphy-Have you check console for any errors?

Comment: @-coder:  No errors in application at all

Comment: anyone have any suggestions?  even anything i could try, this is really annoying :(

Comment: Visual Studio does not recognise AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager. I can only use the asp:ToolkitScriptManager, which is just showing the black box.

Answer (score 0):

It was something in my web.config, not 100% sure what but I was messing around with it and got it working fine.  So if anyone else has this issue it's probably something in your web.config :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```